# Problem with breakpoints while debugging in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I set a breakpoint in one of the class. while debugging my vb.net winform project, the breakpoint moving to the next line which dont have any code. I could not understand what was wrong? I cleaned up my solution and re-build my solution but could not resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this on every line? or on a specific line? if the latter - please cite a specific example. I would also expect the VB and C# implementation to be different here, so tagging both is misleading.

Comment: Usually deleting the `obj` and `bin` folders helps for me.

Comment: This behaviour occurs for specific lines not for every line. In couple of methods of my project, if i add If loop this unexpected behaviour is occuring.

Comment: Could you write us the line you trying to set the breackpoint?

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that the .pdb file is out of sync with the code.  Right click the solution or project and select Clean.  Then rebuild the solution or project and then try to debug.